# make PROPS to call in different component

Tags: reactjs, react-props

how do i set these let variable to become a prop and then to call that prop in a different component to use in a chart.

```
let HP = Response.data.stats[0].base_stat;
  let DMG = Response.data.stats[2].base_stat;
  let ATK = Response.data.stats[1].base_stat;
  let SPECATK = Response.data.stats[3].base_stat;
  let SPECDEF = Response.data.stats[4].base_stat;
  let SPEED = Response.data.stats[5].base_stat;


useEffect(() => {
axios
  .get("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?offset=0&limit=100")
  .then((response) => {
    let pokemons = response.data.results;
    const pokeData = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < pokemons.length; i++) {
      pokeData.push({
        name: pokemons[i].name,
        url: pokemons[i].url,
      });
    }
      let startItem = pokeData.map((item) => (
        <Card pname={item.name} plink={item.url} />
      ));
    setgenPokeListItem(startItem);
  });

axios
  .get("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?offset=0&limit=100")
  .then((response) => {
    let pokemons = response.data.results;
    const pokeData2 = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < pokemons.length; i++) {
      pokeData2.push({
        name: pokemons[i].name,
        url: pokemons[i].url,
      });
    }
    let battleItem = pokeData2.map((item) => (
      <PokeListItem2 pname={item.name} plink={item.url} />
    ));
    setgenPokeListItem2(battleItem);
  });
  setPokeStats(localStorage.getItem("PokemonOne").split(','));
  setPokeStats2(localStorage.getItem("PokemonTwo").split(','));
  }, []);
```

.

```
const Card = (props) => {

  function showPoke() {
axios.get(props.plink).then((Response) => {
  
  let hp = document.getElementById("hp");
  let dmg = document.getElementById("dmg");
  let atk = document.getElementById("atk");
  let specatk = document.getElementById("spec-atk");
  let specdef = document.getElementById("spec-def");
  let speed = document.getElementById("speed");
  let imgURL = Response.data.sprites.front_default;
  let imgStyle = document.getElementById("imge");

  let HP = Response.data.stats[0].base_stat;
  let DMG = Response.data.stats[2].base_stat;
  let ATK = Response.data.stats[1].base_stat;
  let SPECATK = Response.data.stats[3].base_stat;
  let SPECDEF = Response.data.stats[4].base_stat;
  let SPEED = Response.data.stats[5].base_stat;
 


  let PokemonOne = [HP, DMG, ATK, SPECATK, SPECDEF, SPEED];
  localStorage.setItem("PokemonOne", PokemonOne)
  
 hp.innerHTML = `Health:  ` + Response.data.stats[0].base_stat;
 dmg.innerHTML = `Damage:   ` +Response.data.stats[2].base_stat;
 atk.innerHTML = `attack:  ` +Response.data.stats[1].base_stat;
 specatk.innerHTML = `special-attack:   ` +Response.data.stats[3].base_stat;
 specdef.innerHTML = `special-defence:   ` +Response.data.stats[4].base_stat;
 speed.innerHTML = `speed:   ` +Response.data.stats[5].base_stat;

  imgStyle.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + imgURL + ")";
  document.getElementById("imge").style.backgroundImage =
    "'url(" + Response.data.sprites.front_default.url + ")'";
 });
 }

return (
<>
  <div className="poke-list-item">
    <a
      onClick={() => {
        showPoke();
      }}
    >
      <h3 id="bttn">{props.pname}</h3>
    </a>

 
  </div>
 </>
 );
 };

export default Card;
```

so here i added the main component in which the cards are being generated it an then i added the other "Card" component where im actually getting that data, so as you can see i set the data to local storage in the card component and then i get that data again in the main component, i then add that PokeStats into my chart and i get the data, but when selecting a new Pokemon the data doesn't change, when i reload the page i get the new data showing on the charts but the poke is gone again becuase thats not using localstorage, so i just want to get that data being showed in the charts same time as the card,

Comment: Hey there. Maybe you can give us some more details here, as right now I do not understand your problem yet. Maybe you can share the rest of the code of your component, what you already tried and possible errors you get?

Comment: okay so my code is a bit confusing but il post more maybe you can see, im basically calling this component and it generates a pokemon card for me, now i want that same data in the main component to be displayed on charts, i save that data using localstorage and then it does show on the charts, but when i select a new pokemon the charts dont update, they only update once i refresh the page.